# Возвращаемый тип main должен быть int, а не void

Tags: c++

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int var = 1;

void global(void)
{
    cout << "Global var = " << var << endl;
    return;
}


}
void main(void)
{
    int var = 100;
    global();
    cout << "Main var = " << var << endl;
    cout << "Main var = " << ::var << endl;
    system("pause");
    return;
}
```

Comment: не понимаю ничего

Comment: **int** main(void)

Comment: main: функция должна возвращать значения

Comment: @Андрей, поменяйте `return;` на `return 0;` в конце функции main.

Comment: return **0**; в конце

Comment: И? Где сам вопрос-то?

Answer (score 1):

Конечно, согласно стандарту - cм. раздел 6.8.3.1 стандарта (например, [тут](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2019/n4820.pdf)).

> Its type shall have C++ language linkage and it shall have a declared return type of type int